# time() Function Segfaults with g++ -static Compiled on Centos 6 and Run on Debian 10

Tags: c++, linux, debian

folks! I am writing software that must install and run on as many flavors of Linux as possible, but I must be able to compile it on a single Jenkins slave.

Right now this mostly works. But I have run into a case whereby a special combination of things will produce a segfault on Debian 10, but not on any of my numerous other supported flavors of Linux. I have been able to reproduce this in 3 different apps (some of which have been working for years), including the simplified prototype I have listed below.

```
// g++ -g -o ttt -static tt.cpp
// The above compile of this code on Centos 6 will produce a segfault
// when run on Debian 10, but not on any other tested flavor of Linux.
// Dozens of them. The version of g++ is 4.7.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int _argc, char* _argv[])
{
  srand(time(0));
  printf("success\n");
  return 0;
}
```

What I have found by running each of my 3 apps on Debian 10 with gdb is that it will segfault under these conditions.

1. They must be compiled with the -static flag. If I don't use -static, it works fine, regardless on which flavor it is compiled.
2. They must call the time() function. It doesn't really matter how I call it, but it must be called. I tried the usual suspects like passing a NULL pointer and passing a real pointer. It always segfaults when the app is compiled statically.
3. They must be compiled on Centos 6 and run on Debian 10. If I compile statically on Debian 10, the prototype works fine.

So here are my constraints that I am working under.

1. I have to compile on one Linux slave, because I am distributing just one binary. Keeping track of multiple binaries and which one goes on what Linux flavor is not really an option.
2. I have to compile statically or it creates incompatibilities on other supported flavors of Linux.
3. I have to use an older Linux flavor, also for the sake of compatibility. It doesn't have to be Centos, but it has to produce binaries that will run on Centos, as well as numerous other flavors.
4. I have to use g++ 4.7 also for code compatibility.

In your answers, I am hoping for some kind of code trick. Maybe a good, reliable replacement for the time() function. Or a suggestion for another flavor of Linux that is compatible with Debian 10.

Bonus points would go to whoever is able to explain the black magic of why a basic, ubiquitous function like time() would be completely compatible on Debian 9, but segfaults on Debian 10 ONLY when it is compiled statically on Centos 6...

**EDIT:**

strace on the Centos 6 server:

```
execve("./ttt", ["./ttt"], [/* 37 vars */]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="testcent6", ...}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x238c000
brk(0x238d180)                          = 0x238d180
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x238c860)      = 0
brk(0x23ae180)                          = 0x23ae180
brk(0x23af000)                          = 0x23af000
gettimeofday({1585687633, 358976}, NULL) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f682c82f000
write(1, "success\n", 8success
)                = 8
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

strace on the Debian 10 server:

```
execve("./ttt", ["./ttt"], 0x7fff0430dfd0 /* 18 vars */) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="deletemedebian10", ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x1f6f000
brk(0x1f70180)                          = 0x1f70180
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x1f6f860)      = 0
brk(0x1f91180)                          = 0x1f91180
brk(0x1f92000)                          = 0x1f92000
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xffffffffff600400} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable is trying to use the vsyscall interface to implement the syscall used for the `time` function.

This interface has been deprecated in favor of the vdso for a long time. It was dropped completely a while back, but can still be emulated.

Debian 10 seems to have disabled the vsyscall emulation, which is done for security reasons because it may make attacks easier. You should be able to re-enable the emulation by passing the kernel command line option `vsyscall=emulate` at startup, of course with the mentioned security repercussions, if that is an option.

The glibc version on CentOS 6 seems to be 2.12, which is too old to make use of the vdso. So to compile a compatible binary for newer kernel configuations, you need at least glibc 2.14 instead. I don't know whether this can be easily installed on CentOS or whether it will work correctly with the kernel shipped with it.

You should also consider whether you really need a fully static binary. You could link everything statically except libc.